# Can't make a regular expression to work

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var textoNotes = "e|-----------------|B|-----------------|G|-----------------|D|-----------------|A|-----------------|E|3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3|";

var filterChords = /(\(|[^(e|B|G|D|A|E)|]+|\))/g;

var arr = filterChords.exec(textoNotes);
```

This returns:

```
arr[0] = -----------------
arr[1] = -----------------
```

but, This is what I want:

```
arr[0] = -----------------
arr[1] = -----------------
arr[2] = -----------------
arr[3] = -----------------
arr[4] = -----------------
arr[5] = 3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3
```

Thanks you all, and after this I want to get each value in a diferent value.

Comment: What is the output that you want? Make yourself clearer.

Comment: Have you tested your regex on https://regex101.com? It looks fine, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: yes, nad works in regex but here no.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cV9oS1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your regex misbehaves as you tried to use groups inside a character class. In `(\(|[^(e|B|G|D|A|E)|]+|\))`, you have 3 alternatives:

1) `\(` matching a literak `(`
 2) `[^(e|B|G|D|A|E)|]+` matching 1 or more characters other than `(`, `e`...
 3) `\)` matching  a literal `)`.

You can use the following regex:

```
[eBGDAE]\|[^|]+\|
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG1bL4/2)

The regex:

- `[eBGDAE]` - matches 1 letter from the range
- `\|` - matches a literal `|`
- `[^|]+` - 1 or more characters other than `|`
- `\|` - 1 literal `|`.

Note that to make sure you match 1 letter in the beginning, you may use a `\b` word boundary:

```
\b[eBGDAE]\|[^|]+\|
```

JS snippet:

```js
var re = /\b[eBGDAE]\|[^|]+\|/g; 
var str = 'e|-----------------|B|-----------------|G|-----------------|D|-----------------|A|-----------------|E|3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3|';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[0]);    
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += m[0] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

The `res` will contain the array of the values required, and `document...` is only for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't match what you want it seems. I would try using something like below (assuming I am understanding your question correctly, as it's a bit unclear).

```
text.match(/[e|B|G|D|A|E]\|(.+)\|/g);
```

`str.match()` will output an array of values.

A good place to test your regex is http://www.regexr.com or other similar site.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
text.match(/[^\|eBGDAE]+/g);
```

Which will just match any stream of characters not on this list including pipes?

Answer (score 0):

So `|` is one of the special characters that you should escape this which exists outside of `[]`;

```
<script>
var textoNotes = "e|-----------------|B|-----------------|G|-----------------|D|-----------------|A|-----------------|E|3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3|";
var filterChords = /[eBGDAE]\|[^eBGDAE|]+\|/g;
var arr;
while (arr = filterChords.exec(textoNotes)) {
    alert(arr);
}
</script>
```